# I am the sole administrator of a Telegram channel with no owner. How can I get the ownership transferred over?

Tags: telegram

I am the only administrator of a Telegram channel. The owner is out.  Will the channel be transferred to me and if so what is the timeline?  I'm the sole administrator and can't cope with the workload and don't want to abandon the 11K members.

Comment: Have you contacted Telegram support through the app?